# How to play Audio file from resource directory in android

Tags: android, audio, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I'm not able to play a small 2 second audio clip. I have tried every permutation mentioned in stackOverflow similar to this problem. Nothing is working for me even the solution that seem to be work for others.
I don't know whether it's because I don't have a physical device to test on or something.

I'm getting Activity not found error :

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.category.ACTION_VIEW dat=R.raw.song_name.mp3 }
```

My code for playing audio to :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("R.raw.song_name.mp3");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

My file is stored at :

> res/raw/song_name.mp3

I haven't done anything extra on AndroidManifest.xml.
I'm running this app on emulator. Is this causing this error ?

Comment: `res/raw/song_name.mp3` .That is not a 'local directory`. Please put the mp3 as file somewhere on your device first.

Comment: Audio file has to be included as part of my APK. By 'local directory' I mean I don't need to download that file. I can simply access from a resource directory. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using Intent you can use MediaPlayer class.

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.song_name.mp3);
mp.start();
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Unfortunately Intent is compulsory. I'm working on Intent chapter.

Comment: Maybe you can do it intent but why are you trying to do it with this. You can easily do it with the help of Mediaplayer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code is not complete with respects to broadcasting and 
mediaPlayer

I suggest you to read about media player here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

for intents you may check here
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html

```
//to play a local file you could do it this way 

 //create a new media player
        MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
//obtain the source
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource("path/to/youraudiofile.mp3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//prepare the player
        try {
            mPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//now start the player to begin playing the audio
        mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Actually, I don't have to create an object to handle the player part. I'm trying to delegate my activity -- playing music -- to default media player of android via intent. I have never used this feature so I'm bit confuse on playing audio and video part.

Comment: Hi Biken, Any luck with this? were you able to accomplish playing you audio file via intent?